# How to inject value from property file into field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some class:

```
public class MyResources {

    @Value("${my.value}") // value always is null!!!
    private String PATH_TO_FONTS_FOLDER;
}
```

and I have a property file:

```
my.value=/tmp/path
```

and my config class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyBeanConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyResources myResources() throws Exception 
    {
        return new MyResources();
    }
}
```

How can I inject property from my property file into this class field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mark `MyResources` with the `@Component` annotation, for Spring to be able to manage that bean.

This will do the job:

```
@Component
public class MyResources {

    @Value("${my.value}") // value always is null!!!
    private String PATH_TO_FONTS_FOLDER;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to move `@Value("${my.value}")` to `MyBeanConfig`, and add a constructor to `MyResources` which accepts the value.  For example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyBeanConfig {
    @Value("${my.value}")
    private String PATH_TO_FONTS_FOLDER;

    @Bean
        public MyResources myResources() throws Exception {
        return new MyResources(PATH_TO_FONTS_FOLDER);
    }
}
```

But based on the example, there's no need for `MyBeanConfig`.  Simply mark `MyResources` as @Component (or other as appropriate) to allow Spring to manage the creation of the instance.  If Spring creates the instance (instead of using `new` from the example), then the @Value will be injected.